# finding type of Object c#

Tags: c#, casting

I want to write a single method to be used from another thread to change texts and colors in a several amount of `button`s `textBox`es etc.

I would like it to be something like

```
    public void ChangeUIPropertys(Object UIObject , Color color , string Text , ... )
    {
        switch (UIObject.GetType)
        {
            //switch cases 
            //...
            //...
            case Textbox :
             {
             //put here correct method with Invoke for correct cross Thread behavior 
             //DoSomething
             }
        }
    }
```

What is the correct way to implement something like that ?

Comment: Is this really going to end up looking cleaner than just letting the other thread do an `Invoke` with a lambda/delegate that directly sets the properties its interested in?

Comment: I suspect this is a violation of some design principle or another. The worker thread should not access the view directly. It should alter an object that the view is bound to. The view should be responsible for determining which controls change state when the underlying model changes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *as* operator:

```
  TextBox textBox = UIObject as TextBox;

  if (null != textBox) {
    // Do what you want with the textBox
  }
```

If you want to change `Text` and `Color` only you can use abstract ***Control*** class:

```
  Control ctrl = UIObject as Control;

  // Both Button and TextBox
  if (null != ctrl) {
    ctrl.BackColor = Color.Red;
    ctrl.Text = "My Text";
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

It is very much obvious that `Object UIObject` is Control, so the definition of the Method can be changed like

```
public void ChangeUIPropertys(Control UIObject , Color color , string Text)
{
    // to check control type
    if (control is TextBox)
    {
        var tb = (TextBox)control;
        // apply changes

    }
    else if (control is Label)
    {
         // do the same
    }
}
```

In thread safe way

```
public void ChangeUIPropertys(Control UIObject , Color color , string Text)
{
    // to make whole operation thread safe

    var action = delegate {
        // to check control type
        if (control is TextBox)
        {
            var tb = (TextBox)control;
            // apply changes

        }
        else if (control is Label)
        {
             // do the same
        }
    };

    if (control.InvokeRequired)
        control.Invoke(action);
    else
        action.Invoke();

}
```

Comment: down voter, please leave a comment, so i can at least know what mistake I did.

Answer (score 2):

You can't with a `switch`. You should use an `if`, possibly:

```
if (UIObject is TextBox)
{
    // use UIObject
}
```

Or, if you want to reuse `UIObject` as `TextBox`:

```
TextBox tb = UIObject as TextBox;
if (tb != null)
{
    // use tb
}
```

If calling from another thread, make sure to use `Invoke` on the object to use the right thread.

Comment: another better one would be to do a cast using "as" which then means you can do what you need to do if the object is successfully casted to the specified type rather than having to go in the if block then do a cast...then finally do what you need to do with that casted object.

Answer (score 1):

Since the [`Control`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control(v=vs.110).aspx) base class implements `Text` and other properties you mentioned you can just use

```
foreach(var control in this.Controls.OfType<Control>())
    control.Text = "new text";
```

Note: this assumes windows form, but other versions of this answer are available

Comment: can You please expend on the topic , How can I use it for my problem (control certien textBox/Button/etc...)

Comment: @LordTitiKaka - I don't know enough about what type of project you are making (i.e my answer uses elements from winforms) to assist more directly, hit would depend on how you are calling `ChangeUIPropertys`

Answer (score 1):

Although a `case` statement can be made to deal with dispatching here ([demo](http://ideone.com/UJzJwc)) it would not be reliable. Same goes for using a `typeof` based chain of conditionals.

A better alternative would be using a built-in dispatching mechanism with `dynamic`:

```
public void ChangeUIPropertys(dynamic UIObject, Color color , string Text , ... ) {
    //                        ^^^^^^^
    ChangeUiPropertyImpl(UIObject, color, text);
}
private void ChangeUIPropertysImpl(Textbox tb, Color color , string Text , ...) {
    tb.SetColor(color);
}
private void ChangeUIPropertysImpl(Label lbl, Color color , string Text , ...) {
    lbl.SetColor(color);
}
```

Once you tell C# that `UIObject` is `dynamic`, it would find the best-fitting override of the `ChangeUIPropertysImpl` method at runtime. This provides a very fast alternative to a `switch` statement.

Comment: so it is like switch bt each case is differce only with the unknown parameter ?

Comment: @LordTitiKaka Yes, `ChangeUiPropertyImpl` call inside `ChangeUIPropertys` behaves pretty much like a `switch` based on the run-time type of the `UIObject` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a good opportunity to [replace the conditional with polymorphism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NCsoEEz_Ta0).  You might define an abstract object such as:

```
abstract class UIObject
{
    abstract public void ChangeColor(Color color);
    // other operations
}
```

For each UI element on which you can perform this operation, you define a concrete implementation:

```
class TextBoxObject : UIObject
{
    private TextBox uiElement;

    public TextBoxObject(TextBox textBox)
    {
        uiElement = textBox;
    }

    override public void ChangeColor(Color color)
    {
        // change the color of the text box
    }

    // other operations
}
```

Then the consuming code would operate on the abstraction, not the (potentially changing) set of implementations:

```
public void ChangeUIProperties(UIObject uiObject, Color color, string Text, ... )
{
    uiObject.ChangeColor(color);
    // other operations
}
```

This would be a more object-oriented approach, encapsulating the implementation-specific functionality into polymorphic objects rather than long conditional expressions.  From the perspective of the consuming code the type essentially *doesn't matter*, the implementation details are encapsulated behind the abstraction.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have the type of the object, just compare it to `typeof(Textbox)` etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could to that to avoid 2 cas (1 for IS and one after to use the control) :

```
var textbox = UIObject as Textbox;
if(textbox != null)
{
    // change color
}

var button = UIObject as Button;
if(button != null)
{
    // change color
}
```